# Ternary operator on System::Boolean variable

Tags: c++-cli

How to use ternary operator with System::Boolean? This sample code always returns true:

```
bool Test(Boolean^ value)
{
  return value ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Boolean is a value type.  Passing a boxed copy of it as an argument make no sense at all.  And of course made your code fail since the object is never nullptr.  Casting it back to bool just burns cpu cycles for no good reason.  Remove the ^

Comment: Boolean is automatically convertible to bool in C++/CLI, so why would you use the ternary operator at all?  If you drop the ^ as Hans suggested, you can just return `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own premature question, this code works:

```
bool Test(Boolean^ value)
{
  return (bool)value ? true : false;
}
```

EDIT: better yet (and following Hans' and Matt's advice) this code works better:

```
bool Test(Boolean value)
{
  return value ? true : false;
}
```

Or, because Boolean and bool are convertible this is also good code, which relies on automatic conversion that happens elsewhere. Example has very little sense except for showing the ternary operator:

```
bool Test(bool value)
{
  return value ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: As Hans suggested--don't do this, you'll incur boxing and unboxing penalties unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `System::Boolean` is wrong in the first place and it has nothing to do with ternary operator. Never pass a value types as reference.

Regadless of unnecessary penalities, the code in your answer will work but not in C#. The compiler will complain when you want to call `bool Test(Boolean^ value)` function. Because there is no concept of referenced value type in C#.