# System::Boolean and bool aren't comparable in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, boolean

I'm using Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Pro. Following code snippet will fail to compile:

```
int main(void) {
    System::Boolean^ foobar = true;
    if (foobar == true) {
        System::Console::Write("yeah!");
    }
}
```

It gives following errors:

```
1>.\main.cpp(3) : warning C4805: '==' : unsafe mix of type 'System::Boolean ^' and type 'bool' in operation
1>.\main.cpp(3) : error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'int' to 'System::Boolean ^'
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>        No standard conversion exists from the boxed form of the arithmetic type to the target type
1>.\main.cpp(3) : error C2040: '==' : 'System::Boolean ^' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
```

Following code compiles fine:

```
int main(void) {
    System::Boolean^ foobar = true;
    if (foobar->Equals(true)) {
        System::Console::Write("yeah!");
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there better way to compare System::Boolean with bool in C++/CLI than using ->Equals() and ->CompareTo()?

Comment: Why do you compare booleans to true to begin with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ternary operator on System::Boolean variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744929/ternary-operator-on-systemboolean-variable).

Comment: Frédéric, thanks for the link. The solution is dropping `^` character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System::Boolean^` is a *reference* to a (boxed) boolean. Use `System::Boolean` instead.

Comment: You just made me rethink the ^ symbol completely.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if (foobar == true)
```

use:

```
if (foobar)
```

Or use the normal bool if it's for simple logic:

```
int main(void) {
    bool foobar = true;
    if (foobar) {
        System::Console::Write("yeah!");
    }
}
```

The problem in VS is that bool is an int, so comparing objects with integers doesn't make sense.